# Default Mac 500GB partitions

Tags: macos, mac, partitioning, gpt, testdisk

I am trying repair hosed partitions on a Macbook. It has a 500 GB drive and as far as I know, it was a standard install with no Bootcamp. I ran testdisk and it found:

EFI System 40 409639
Mac HFS 439566 975533517

I used gdisk to delete and then recreate the partitions as testdisk showed them but it still won't boot. I then tried every other variation I could think of but have not been able to fix it as of yet. I have tried it with another third partition between the ones shown above. I have tried every possible variation of the partition codes being ef00, af00, af05 and ab00.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help? I keep looking on google for someone who has listed the default partitioning scheme for a 500 GB, but I can't find it. Does anybody here on the forum have a 500 GB HD in their Mac and could give me their partitioning so I can match it? All the ones I see on google are setup with Bootcamp and that won't help.  Can anybody help? Anybody have any ideas at all for restoring this HDD so that I can resuce files or even boot? Thanks!!

Comment: I think I have finally gotten the partition table right (maybe) by using random tables from google. Here is what I have:

Comment: Partition 1 40 409639 EF00; Partition 2 409640 975503598 AF00 (also tried AF05); Partition 3 975503599 976773134 AB00 (labeled "Recovery HD"). However, I am still getting a question mark at boot and cannot mount or fsck.hfsplus the partitions. I get an error with fsck.hfsplus saying that there are no hfs signatures. Does this partition table look right? Any idea why fsck.hfsplus isn't happy?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply james.. Perhaps this will help someone down the road. I am curious what ended up happening in your situation?

Macbook Pro, Toshiba 500GB SATA drive. Computer recently refused to start up, blinking question mark folder on screen. Booting off a Mac OS X CD did not help, Disk Utility could not verify or repair the drive. Gave the error:

> Checking storage system. Problems were encountered during repair of
>   the partition map.

And the data you were looking for (though the sector count isn't identical):

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MK5065GS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 976773168s
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start       End         Size        File system  Name                  Flags
 1      40s         409639s     409600s     fat32        EFI System Partition  boot
 2      409640s     876032239s  875622600s               Macintosh HD
 3      876032240s  877301775s  1269536s    hfs+         Booter

Disk /dev/sdd: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 99471365 sectors (47.4 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       876032239   417.5 GiB   AF05  Macintosh HD
   3       876032240       877301775   619.9 MiB   AB00  Booter
```